# C# How can I get timer to tick properly?

Tags: c#

Making an application that can take Youtube links and add them to a queue and then play them until the queue is empty. Currently my timer1_Tick doesn't seem to be executing and I'm not sure why :(

```
//timer1_Tick
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        timer1.Stop();
        Video.Movie = "";
        q.Dequeue();
        qq.Dequeue();
}
```

Here is the meat and potatoes

```
if (e.ChatMessage.Message.StartsWith("!songrequest"))
            {
                var myString = e.ChatMessage.Message.ToString();
                var newString = myString.Remove(0, myString.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
                var getID = newString.Remove(0, newString.IndexOf('=') + 1);
                var vUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/v/" + getID + "&autoplay=1";
                var vUrlString = vUrl.ToString();
                q.Enqueue(vUrlString);
                qq.Enqueue(getID.ToString());
                string[] array = new string[q.Count];
                string[] array2 = new string[qq.Count];
                q.CopyTo(array, 0);
                qq.CopyTo(array2, 0);

                if (timer1.Enabled == false)
                    {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                        {
                         YouTubeVideo video = new Helix.YouTubeVideo(array2[i]);
                         var gDur = getDuration(video.duration);
                         string[] time = gDur.ToString().Split(' ');
                         int min = int.Parse(time[0]);
                         int sec = int.Parse(time[1]);
                         int msm = min * 60000;
                         int mss = sec * 1000;
                         int dur = msm + mss;
                         timer1.Interval = dur;

                         Video.Movie = array[i];
                        timer1.Start();
                        client.SendMessage("Now playing: " + video.title + ".");
                        client.SendMessage($"Timer set to { dur } ms.");
                    }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    client.SendMessage("It's still running somehow.");
                  }
```

Comment: where's your binding for tick event?

Comment: Sorry? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: People come here, copy and paste most of their code, don't even copy the relevant part (like what references the tick handler) ---- and to top it of, you don't even have the effort to spend 5 seconds formatting your code or remove irrelevant things before posting? I'm sorry but that's frustrating.

Comment: nevermind, check my ans hope this helps :)

Comment: Apologies, @caesay If it wasn't apparent I have no idea what I'm doing and I'm looking for guidance. Please forgive my ignorance. I included everything that is in the post because I'm not sure what is or what isn't useful/relevant. What do you mean by 'like what references the tick handler'? I'm (hopefully) calling the timer to start after the next value in queue comes up then it (should but doesn't) stop.

Comment: Surely this code does not run on the UI thread, it would bog down the UI noticeable.  The Timer class is only partly thread-safe, starting it on a worker thread does not produce a Tick.  Belongs in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler of a BackgroundWorker.  Albeit that it isn't likely to be necessary at all anymore when you get this right.

Comment: @JosephFuller Hi does the timer1_Tick event hit at all?

Comment: @HansPassant I'll attempt to look into that

Comment: @David It doesn't seem too, I've added a messagebox `MessageBox.Show("Tick");` but after its supposed to tick it never comes up I think it has to do with what Hans has said

Answer (score 0):

here you are checking disabled timer and only if it is not enabled it will go into condition..

```
 if (timer1.Enabled == false)
                    {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                        {
                         YouTubeVideo video = new Helix.YouTubeVideo(array2[i]);
                         var gDur = getDuration(video.duration);
                         string[] time = gDur.ToString().Split(' ');
                         int min = int.Parse(time[0]);
                         int sec = int.Parse(time[1]);
                         int msm = min * 60000;
                         int mss = sec * 1000;
                         int dur = msm + mss;
                         timer1.Interval = dur;

                         Video.Movie = array[i];
                        timer1.Start();
                        client.SendMessage("Now playing: " + video.title + ".");
                        client.SendMessage($"Timer set to { dur } ms.");
                    }
                  }
```

so if you are starting timer, on timer1.Start(), you need to enable it first.

try

```
  if (timer1.Enabled == false)
                        {
timer1.Enabled = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                            {
                             YouTubeVideo video = new Helix.YouTubeVideo(array2[i]);
                             var gDur = getDuration(video.duration);
                             string[] time = gDur.ToString().Split(' ');
                             int min = int.Parse(time[0]);
                             int sec = int.Parse(time[1]);
                             int msm = min * 60000;
                             int mss = sec * 1000;
                             int dur = msm + mss;
                             timer1.Interval = dur;

                             Video.Movie = array[i];
                            timer1.Start();
                            client.SendMessage("Now playing: " + video.title + ".");
                            client.SendMessage($"Timer set to { dur } ms.");
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: It looks like the timer is starting but not ending, I'm using a short 12 second video to test it out. The interval is set to 12000ms but afterwards it seems the timer still doesn't set the video.movie to nothing

Comment: this might not be the problem with timer stop but something else wrong going into code, take a close look and try to put messagebox if timer_tick event hit after you stop it. Consider accepting ans if your basic prob is solved. :)

Comment: Using `MessageBox.Show("Tick");` after calling the timer to stop but the messagebox does not show

Comment: tht mean your tick event is not working, it should be referenced properly, consider deleting this tick and double click on timer1 on gui (easiest) else modify design refrences

Comment: That is how it is done already but just in case I went in deleted the timer, remade it, double clicked it and added in the old events and the issue still persists :(

Comment: apologies for not having close loop, on it I can see you are starting and timer and setting interval into for loop. why it is need to have for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the timer, its defaulted to false.

[image: caputure]

Comment: I've added `timer1.Enabled = true;` before starting the timer and it has made no change in the tick event

Comment: timer1.Enabled = true; then timer1.Start()

Comment: Yes that is how it is being used currently